# Style a kable table knitted to pdf

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, kaggle

I'm using kable to output a table from a data.frame in a R markdown document that is parsed to pdf.

This is the output:
[image]

I would like to style the table. Specifically I'd like to:

- Increase cell height. The padding argument passed to kable() function didn't have effect.
- Make the headings bold. (No idea about this).

I call kaggle() in a function that is then called into the chunk in the .Rmd file.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can either use eg `xtable` to generate a fine-tuned LaTeX table instead of markdown or apply a custom LaTeX template for `pdflatex` -- see the `knitr` documentation. Alternatively, use `pander::pander` instead of `kable`, which will at least make the headings bold (but not increase the cell height) -- with a few other extra options: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables

Comment: so kable is not customizable?

Comment: `Hmisc::latex` provides the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether you tried already, but the **[kableExtra](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)** package offers a lot more features than kable. You could simply pipe your kable call into row specifications with

`%>% row_spec (0, bold = T)`

I couldn't find an option for cell height there. In case you'd generally want to change it you could either pass it as an option into the YAML header or change the *default.tex* file.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).